# An error occurred when attempting to open certificate list, the error was: Automation server can't create object

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, activex

I'm trying to fill up a form from [here](https://ipindiaonline.gov.in/epatentfiling/user/NewUserRegistration.aspx) . Upon selecting `Natural Person` from the drop-down menu, a form appears with a button `Add Digital Signature`. Whenever I click on this button, it gives me this error:

```
An error occurred when attempting to open certificate list, the error was: 
Automation server can't create object
```

I've tried enabling the `Initialize and Script Activex controls not marked as safe for scripting` feature from internet option but the same error occurred.
I've tried different versions of Internet Explorer starting from version 6. Can anyone help me ?

Comment: Hi , Is this resolved? I am facing the same

Comment: Yes, You need a digital certificate to be installed from here. https://ipindiaonline.gov.in/epatentfiling/faqs/index.html

Comment: Hi, i facing same issue. Is it website issue or token issue. In 2014 it was working when token was e-pass token . Now in 2019 its not working with WatchData token. IE is able to view my certificates issued by e-mudhra in watchData (PROXKey ) token in internetoptions--> contents --> certificates.  Any help is greatly appriciated.

Answer (score 2):

1)Download capicom_dc_sdk.msi from 
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=25281 
and install.

2)Locate capicom.dll "e.g. C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft CAPICOM 2.1.0.2 SDK\Lib\X86\capicom.dll"

2)Open command prompt with administrator privilege, change directory to directory containing capicom.dll and fire below command
regsvr32 capicom.dll

Comment: i was facing same problem. Then I called e-mudhra (I bought dsc from here ) customer care.  They took access of my laptop via anydesk, and they performed similar operation i.e. 1. downloaded capicom.dll.zip. 2. extracted it. 3. then copied it (capicom.dll) to : This PC > OS (C:) > Windows > SysWOW64.  4.  then run below command as administrator in cmd : regsvr32 capicom.dll . 5. Now I am able to sign up on website ipindiaonline.gov.in

Comment: This process is needed each time you restart your computer.

Comment: @AmbarishKumarShivam How to do this in Chrome browser ? IE is not going to be there in few weeks now.

Answer (score 1):

i was facing same problem. Then I called e-mudhra (I bought dsc from here ) customer care. They took access of my laptop via anydesk, and they performed similar operation i.e.

1. downloaded capicom.dll.zip.
2. extracted it.
3. then copied it (capicom.dll) to : This PC > OS (C:) > Windows > SysWOW64.
4. then run below command as administrator in cmd :
   Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.836]
   (c) 2019 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\WINDOWS\system32>cd ..

C:\Windows>cd SysWOW64

C:\Windows\SysWOW64>regsvr32 capicom.dll

C:\Windows\SysWOW64>

```
5. Now try with Internet Explorer. (Mozilla firefox will not work !)
```

Now I am able to sign up on website ipindiaonline.gov.in

Process is needed each time after you restart your computer.
Please note that running cmd in Administrator mode is necessary.

Comment: what about Chrome ? IE will be removed in few weeks now ?

Answer (score 0):

To people reaching here, I solved it by installing a digital certficate provided by e-patent website. You need to check which class of certificate you want for authentication.
Here's the updated link from where you can download the certificate: 
https://ipindiaonline.gov.in/epatentfiling/faqs/index.html